# Recover Wordpress SuperAdmin

Tags: wordpress

I am administrator in a WP installation (hosted on our own server). In the admin, there is no options for plugins.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194028/plugins-menu-doesnt-appear-in-the-admin-panel) but (apparently) don't have permission to see plugins.
I tried changing my access in database using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64466/making-someone-a-wordpress-administrator-using-phpmyadmin), but already have the highest available

The plugins folder exists and contains plugins.

Looking around the DB tables, I get the impression that this is a multi-site installation. This means that there would be a SuperAdmin role, which can allow admins to access plugins. Heres the source of the problem: the people who may have had that role, left the company a number of years ago and no-one else has access as SuperAdmin since then.

I don't have wp-cli installed on the DB and would rather not have to go through that process.

How can I apply SuperAdmin role to myself via the DB?

Please note: I am not trying to reset a password, I am trying to make myself the SuperAdmin, as we have no SuperAdmins listed.

Comment: Try to reset the super admin password directly in the DB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150571/reset-wordpress-password-via-sql

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo the problem is that I do not have anyone listed as superAdmin - the person left years ago and their account was deleted

Comment: Check if [this](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-wordpress-database/) works. As usual, make a backup first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really in WordPress Multisite you may use e.g. wp-cli to add yourself to super-admins via
`wp super-admin add superadmin2` wp-cli command.

See
https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/super-admin/add/